# Encryption of a 3rd party application plugin

Tags: java, encryption, plugins

I have Created a plugin using java that can be used a with a third party app. I have all the licencing issue resolved.
Is there any way that i can encrypt my plugin so no one can see my embedded code?

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem a few months ago. AFAIK there is no 100% foolproof way to make a jar undecryptable. After all, the JVM needs to be able to read it. And if the JVM can read it so can a user. 
You can make it harder to understand the code by obfuscating or compile the jar ahead-of-time.

I thought this article lists some good possibilities (note that excelsior itself offers such services, so it might be biased)

http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html